# Select a column based on name of a row (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select values of a column based on a value of a row using pandas.

For example:

```
    names  A  B  C  D
    A      1  0  2  0
    A      2  1  0  0
    C      1  0  4  0
    A      2  0  0  0
    D      0  1  2  5
```

As output I want something like:

```
name  value
A     1
A     2
C     4 
A     2
D     5
```

Is there a very fast (efficient) way to do such operation?

Comment: Is the names column in the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try look at `lookup`

```
df.lookup(df.index,df.names)
Out[390]: array([1, 2, 4, 2, 5], dtype=int64)
#df['value']=df.lookup(df.index,df.names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use the multi-purpose apply function:

```
import pandas

data = {
    'names': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D'],
    'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 0],
    'B': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    'C': [2, 0, 4, 0, 2],
    'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

def process_it(row):
    return row[row['names']]

df['selection'] = df.apply(process_it, axis=1)

print(df[['names', 'selection']])
```